# Require HTML files as template String in Browserify when using tsify (Typescript)

Tags: html, templates, typescript, browserify

I would like to `require`/`import` HTML templates as strings into my code. But running in some transpile errors.

This is the revelant Browserify setup I am using:

```
browserify({ basedir: './src' })
    .transform(stringify(['.tpl.html']))
    .add('app.ts')
    .plugin(tsify)
```

In the `app.ts` I want to import a template like so:

```
import template from './app.tpl.html';
console.log(template);
```

Where `app.tpl.html` may look like this:

```
<h1>Hello!</h1>
```

I tried different setups with using `require` over `import`. Using `require` I get the following error:

```
Browserify Error { [TypeScript error: src/components/app.ts(1,9): 
Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.]
message: 'src/components/app.ts(1,9): Error TS2304: Cannot find name \'require\'.',
fileName: 'src/components/app.ts',
line: 1,
column: 9,
name: 'TypeScript error' }
```

Usind `import` the module is not found and I get the following error:

```
Browserify Error { [TypeScript error: src/components/test.ts(1,22): Error TS2307: Cannot find module './test.tpl.html'.]
message: 'src/components/test.ts(1,22): Error TS2307: Cannot find module \'./test.tpl.html\'.',
fileName: 'src/components/test.ts',
line: 1,
column: 22,
name: 'TypeScript error' }
```

I couldn't find an example using "stringify" and "tsify" together. Has anyone a working example who to use HTML templates toghether with "browserify" and "tsify"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to import/require in TypeScript something different than TypeScript module you need to use "native" require function (in this case to be defined by browserify). TypeScript compiler is not aware of that until you tell it.

```
declare function require (id: string): any; // declare there will be 'require' function in the runtime 

var template = require('./app.tpl.html'); // use declared function in pure JS
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use **<amd-depdendency>** comment.

Code like this (menuTemplate.jst is static template file):

```
/// <amd-dependency path="general/menuTemplate.jst" name="menuTemplate" />

import Marionette = require("backbone.marionette");
declare var menuTemplate: string;

class MenuView extends Marionette.ItemView<any> {
  template = menuTemplate;
}
```

produces output (ES 6):

```
/// <amd-dependency path="general/menuTemplate.jst" name="menuTemplate" />
define(["require", "exports", "general/menuTemplate.jst", "backbone.marionette"], function (require, exports, menuTemplate, Marionette) {
    "use strict";
    class MenuView extends Marionette.ItemView {
        constructor(...args) {
            super(...args);
            this.template = menuTemplate;
        }
    }
});
```